# Allow Python App To Continue Running Until User Ends

Tags: python, user-input

I'm pretty new to python and I wrote a simple blackjack card counting app. The app runs and after the user input it ends, I want it to continue asking for the user input and printing the count out. I don't want it to restart, I want it to continue. Ive included the source code. Thanks guys.

```
count = 0

var = int(raw_input("Enter the value of the card: "))

if var == 1 :
      print count + 1
elif var == 2 :
      print count + 1
elif var == 3 :
      print count + 1
elif var == 4 :
      print count + 1
elif var == 5 :
      print count + 1
elif var == 6 :
      print count + 1
elif var == 7 :
      print count + 0
elif var == 8 :
      print count + 0 
elif var == 9 :
      print count + 0 
elif var == 10 :
      print count - 1 
elif var == 11 :
      print count - 1
```

Comment: Have you learned about loops? Search around for examples.

Answer (score 1):

To make your program run until the user stops providing input, you will probably need to put your code in a loop. A `while` loop is usually the best when you don't know ahead of time how long you'll need to loop for.

```
count = 0
while True: # runs forever
    var = int(raw_input("Enter the value of the card: "))

    # if/elif block goes here
```

Once you do this though, you'll find that there's a logic error in your code. Currently you're printing `count + 1` or similar in one of your if/elif blocks each time. However, this doesn't modify the value of `count`, it just prints the new value directly. What I think you'll want to do is change your code to directly modify `count` in the if/else blocks, then write it out in a separate step. You can also combine several of your conditions using `<` or `>`, like this:

```
    if var < 7:
        count += 1
    elif var > 9:
        count -= 1

    print count
```

You could optionally add some extra error checking to make sure the entered value is appropriate (e.g. between 1 and 11), but I've left that off here for clarity.

Comment: I thank you for the answer, but I don't think you understand how card counting works. Because of this your new code wouldn't follow the correct principals and wouldn't provide the right answer. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh and I don't want it to just continue asking the card, I want it to ask and then print out. You don't know anything.

Comment: @KirmaanAboobaker: Um, have you tried my code? I think it will do exactly what you want. I understand the basic principles of counting cards for Black Jack, that you increase the count when you see low cards and decrease it when you see high ones, which is what my code does. It also will always update the count then print the new value after each input. If you want some different solution, you'll need to explain what you want in the question. It will also help to not insult people who take time to answer you.